# EXCEL - How to use two cells for input and output at the same time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have 3 cells, VALUE, DOWNPAYMENT, DOWNPAYMENT %.

The 3rd cell "DOWNPAYMENT %" calculates the percentage of "DOWNPAYMENT" over "VALUE"

Is there a way for the user to have the function to input a number in "DOWNPAYMENT %" cell and get a figure in "DOWNPAYMENT".

What I mean is that if both cells could be used at the same time for input of data and for output of calculation.

Comment: To do that, both cells would have to test the other cell to see if it contained a formula or a value, which would be a circular reference.  The closest you can come is to have two input cells that are separate from the results cells.  The results cells can then display either the input value, if there is one, or a result calculated from the other input value.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx and http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html

For more google `Worksheet_Change` among Excel events.

Idea: In the Worksheet_Change event, check if either of the cells can be recalculated, and do it if possible.

Note that the whole tasks is a bit more complicated than filling in a couple formulas though. Even if it might seem simple from the reading behind the second link.

Comment: -1 because I'm not sure this is an adequate **answer** - it's basically "google worksheet_change; but here are some links." Links go dead and this does not describe *how* one would use the worksheet_change event in this case. Perhaps you could add more detail on how it works so it doesn't become irrelevant if the links go down.